# In which path image files will be copied that I have placed at the root

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift2, xcode8

When I develop apps, I am placing many image files under the root path (the directory which has my project name) on Xcode. I also can see them with Finder in the directory under the root (project name) folder.

I want to know in which directory those image files are copied when users installed the app on their devices, in this case.

I am trying to find those image files with NSHomeDirectory() but failed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: They will be in your app bundle so you have to access them using the `NSBundle` methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSBundle.pathForResource() will give you the right path.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. However, it's should be " NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource()".